# JQuery по нажатию кнопок

Tags: jquery, button

Есть кнопка

```
<button type="button" id="inputstart" class="card-buttonaddtask" >Создать</button>
```

По нажатию пытаюсь добавить элемент с поля ввода в список.

```
    // нажимаем ввод события
    $('#title').on('keydown', function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        // Оцениваем, есть ли контент в текстовом поле
        if ($(this).val() === '') {
            alert('Незаконная операция')
        } else {
            // Считываем исходные данные, хранящиеся локально
            var local = getData();
            // Затем добавляем последние данные в локальный массив
            local.push({ title: $(this).val(), done: false });
            // Затем сохраняем локальный массив в локальное хранилище  
            saveData(local)
            // Выводим данные на страницу
            load()
            // Содержимое текстового поля пусто
            $(this).val('');
        }
    }
});
```

Когда ввожу текст в поле ввода, то элемент попадает в список только по нажатию на Enter.
Как выполнять код по нажатию на мою кнопку? Помогите, пожалуйста

Answer (score 1):

для этого нужно узнать код клавиши, у вас он тут используется

```
e.keyCode === 13
```

для этого можно сделать так

```js
$('body').keydown(function(e) {

  console.log(`Кнопка ${e.originalEvent.key} ее код ${e.keyCode}`)

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
кликните на эту область и нажимайте кнопки на клавиатуре, будут коды
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 $('#inputstart').click(function (e) {    
        // Оцениваем, есть ли контент в текстовом поле
        if ($('#title').val() === '') {
            alert('Незаконная операция')
        } else {
            // Считываем исходные данные, хранящиеся локально
            var local = getData();
            // Затем добавляем последние данные в локальный массив
            local.push({ title: $('#title').val(), done: false });
            // Затем сохраняем локальный массив в локальное хранилище  
            saveData(local)
            // Выводим данные на страницу
            load()
            // Содержимое текстового поля пусто
            $('#title').val('');
        }    
});
```